# NodeJS Monitoring Website (Worker Threads?/Multi Process?)

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, monitoring

I am doing small project of application that will monitor some servers.
It will base on telnet port check, ping, and also it will use libraries to connect directly to databases (MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL) to check their status.

I wonder what will be the best effective solution for this idea, currently with around 30 servers it works quite smooth, around 2.5sec to check status for all of them (running async). However I am worried that in the future with more servers it might get worse. Hence thinking about using some alternative like Worker Threads maybe? or some multi processing? Any ideas? Everything is happening in internal network so I do not expect huge latency.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the PM2 cluster mode:

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I'll take a look on it. However it's just for improving the application itself. Now my question is how to improve the code itself to make it possible. I wonder if there are any examples/open source projects like this (couldn't find any recently updated).

Answer (score 0):

The telnet stuff is TCP, which Node.js does very well using OS-level networking events. The connections to databases can vary. In the case of Oracle, you'll likely be using the node-oracledb. Those are SQL*Net connections that rely on the OCI libs and Node.js' thread pool. The thread pool defaults to four threads, but you can grow it up to 128 per Node.js process. See this doc for info:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-143-connections-threads-and-parallelism

Having said all that, other than increasing the size of the thread pool, I wouldn't recommend you make any changes. Why fight fires before they're burning? No need to over-engineer things. You're getting acceptable performance given the current number of servers you have.

How many servers do you plan to add in, say, 5 years? What's the difference in timing if you run the status checks for half of the servers vs all of them? Perhaps you could use that kind of data to make an educated guess as to where things would go.

As you add new ones, keep track of the total time to check the status. Is it slipping? If so, look into where the time is being spent and write the solution that will help.

Comment: Thank you for answer Dan! I'll check your link and then answer to your questions as soon as possible.

Comment: So I've checked the link and proposal overall, however it's not something that I'm gonna sure. As far I understand it's related to connection pool which is not being used in my application, and not gonna be. Everytime that application perform check it has to be connection from scratch to make sure that connectivity with database is fully working. I've worked quite lot with Oracle and I know that connection pools are still established even if database has issues so in such case I'll not see the real status. But anyway, this is second topic. The major one is the performance.

Comment: What I am worried about is how many parallel tcp connections application can do at once, at this moment I have around 30 connections, it works fine. But I am worried that in future the system might get overloaded or some OS/network related stuff might get overloaded with so huge amount of tcp attempts at once (let's say 200-300) I can't imagine OS/or node JS handle 300 TCP connections at one time using parallel. Is it even possible?

Comment: In your case, I agree, the connection pools don't make sense. But there are other tidbits of wisdom in there :) Node.js has been known to scale way beyond 300 TCP connections. This is something you could test, no? Not all TCP connections will be doing something at the same time. When one does, an event occurs and the main thread eventually has to process is. In theory, this could become a problem, in which case you'd scale out with multiple servers. Learning not to over-engineer solutions is counter-intuitive, but it's a valuable skill for all programmers. Let problems drive solutions.